# JS. Обработчик нажатий, перевод к нижний регистр. Запаздывает на один символ

Tags: javascript

Нужно привести все значения к нижнему регистру. Но при вводе "HELLO" выводит только hell. На одну букву обработчик всегда запаздывает, удалением также. Отчего так и как избавиться от этого недуга?

```js
document.querySelector(".i-4").onkeydown = function f4(e) {
  document.querySelector(".out-4").innerHTML = document.querySelector(".i-4").value.toLowerCase();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="i-4">
<div class="out-4"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При попытке что-то напечатать, сперва срабатывает событие `keydown`, потом добавляется символ, потом срабатывает `input`, потом `keyup`. Тест:

```js
let test = document.getElementById('test');

test.addEventListener('keydown', function(){
  console.log( "keydown → " + this.value );
});
test.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
  console.log( "keyup → " + this.value );
});
test.addEventListener('input', function(){
  console.log( "input → " + this.value );
});
```

```html
<input id="test">
```

keyup срабатывает только во время отпускания кнопки, а input - после любого изменения значения - даже если туда что-то скопируют. Поэтому вот:

```js
let i4 = document.querySelector(".i-4");
let out4 = document.querySelector(".out-4");
// Один раз сохранили ссылки на элементы в переменные и всё.
// Чтобы после нажатия каждой кнопки заново по всей странице не искать нужные элементы.

i4.addEventListener('input', function(){
  out4.textContent = i4.value.toLowerCase();
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="i-4">
<div class="out-4"></div>
```

Comment: Благодарю. Как я понял такие задачи следует решать через input, который бдит за любым изменением и проблем не будет)) По поводу ссылок да. Так и делаю обычно. Это я пока учусь разом пытаюсь вкратце написать всё и понять как что и зачем Хотя вижу так не всегда проще.

Comment: @Павел ну, они "родственники") Для ряда задачек для полей ввода. По ситуации.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать **onkeypress** более универсальное отслеживание нажатий. Ну и если вы отслеживаете нажатие, то вместо получения **value** правильно использовать **e.key** иначе нет вообще смысла таким образом слушать по клавише input

```js
document.querySelector(".i-4").onkeypress = function f4(e) {
    document.querySelector('.out-4').textContent += e.key.toLowerCase();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="i-4">
<div class="out-4"></div>
```